# Do we need to close the inputstream explicitely after read ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream?

Tags: java, properties, inputstream

A call to ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream opens an input stream to the underlying resource that gets eventually converted into properties:

```
Properties build = new Properties();
build.load(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(ANT_BUILD));
```

Do we need to explicitly close the stream after loading the properties?

Had a quick look at `java.util.Properties` and it doesn't close the stream!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default `ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(String)` returns a `FileInputStream` wrapped into `BufferedInputStream`.

If you look into [FileInputStream sources](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/io/FileInputStream.java.html) you will see that it has got `finalize` method which closes the stream for you.

But of course it's not a good practice to wait for the heap to grow until garbage collector starts to take care of your streams, and you should always try to close streams yourself.

Answer (score 2):

The specified stream remains open after `load` method returns, so it's your responsibility to close the stream. You need to close the stream explicitly.